# In static generic method , what is the usage of <? extends E>?

Tags: java, generics, static, wildcard

I am reading source code of java collection. I have some troubles with the source code of Interface java.util.List.

In the bottom of source code of Interface java.util.List, there is a method:

```
static <E> List<E> copyOf(Collection<? extends E> coll) {
    return ImmutableCollections.listCopy(coll);
}
```

I want to ask, what is usage of *<? extends E>*.

Can I replace *<? extends E>* with *E*?  Just like this:

```
static <E> List<E> copyOf(Collection<E> coll) {
    return ImmutableCollections.listCopy(coll);
}
```

Are two functions doing same things?

If they are same, why use *<? extends E>*

If they are not same,when I call the method like:

```
List.copyOf(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

what is *?(wildcard)*, and what is *E*?

Is *E* representing Integer?

or *?(wildcard)* representing Integer?

Comment: Essentially, `<? extends E>` allows you to do `List<Object> list = List.copyOf(listOfInteger)`.

Comment: so wehn i call *List.copyOf(listOfInteger)* , the *?(wildcard)* represent Integer, and *E* represents *Object*?